# Excel docs. Query ¿Cómo devolver tabla valor máximo de horas?

Tags: sql, excel, docstrings

Tengo una tabla con Fechas diferentes y hora de registro de acuerdo al momento de registro valga la redundancia Quiero filtrar por horas máxima, que me devuelva la tabla con el máximo de horas Con la intención que si existe una actualización de precio solo me muestre el ultimo registro filtrado por hora pero que devuelva la tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un ejemplo lo que he podido hacer, pero con fecha E logrado filtrar todos los productos con la función MAX, lo cual me devolvió la tabla con todos sus productos Pero existe un error lógico, me devuelve la tabla con doble registro de un producto, pero con diferente precio y diferencia de hora registro Lo para afinar más el filtro, solo necesito que me devuelva la tabla con todos sus productos, pero con el valor máximo de hora

[image: ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es el QUERY en Excel DOCS que realiza, se los comparto para el filtro por fecha máxima

```
= SI.ERROR (QUERY (A: E; "Select * where D = date '" & TEXTO (MAX ($ D: $ D); "AAAA-MM-DD") & "'"; 1); "")
```